# Can I return multiple counters in the same query result (oracle)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I want to retrieve count of all rows match one value and at the same time return a different counter which will count subset of first counter results based on additional condition .

For example I want to retrieve below queries result in one query :

```
Select Count(*), 
from table
where cond1 = '1';

select Count(*)
from table
where cond1 = '1'
And Cond2 ='1';
```

can it be done in one query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using `case` and `sum` like this:

```
select 
   Sum(case when cond1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count1,
   Sum(case when cond1 = 1 and cond2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count2
from table;
```

Answer (score 4):

gmiley's answer is perfectly fine.

However, this one may be a bit faster - especially if cond1 is indexed!

```
select 
   count(*) as count1,
   count(case when cond2 = 1 then 1 end) as count2
from table
where cond1 = 1
```